# getting TypeError: 'TextDetector' object is not callable

Tags: python, callable-object, paddle-paddle

My TextDetector object is a blueprint of a class but still not able to call it.
it was working before but now it is not working. Don't know why it happened. Can anyone of you give me a reason for this TypeError?

```py
import predict_det

#from predict_det import TextDetector

import cv2

#import torch

#device = torch.device('cuda:0')

​

text_detector  = predict_det.TextDetector()

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\pearl\Downloads\AI\Project OCR\OCR_PP_tester\Temp_img_folder\images.jpg')

dt_boxes, elapse = text_detector(img)
```

```
<class 'list'>
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3160/1748103168.py in <module>
      7 text_detector  = predict_det.TextDetector()
      8 img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\pearl\Downloads\AI\Project OCR\OCR_PP_tester\Temp_img_folder\images.jpg')
----> 9 dt_boxes, elapse = text_detector(img)

TypeError: 'TextDetector' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any arg for the TextDetector constructor, thus det_algorithm is 'empty' which raises an error:

```
    if self.det_algorithm == "EAST":
        preds['f_geo'] = outputs[0]
        preds['f_score'] = outputs[1]
    elif self.det_algorithm == 'SAST':
        preds['f_border'] = outputs[0]
        preds['f_score'] = outputs[1]
        preds['f_tco'] = outputs[2]
        preds['f_tvo'] = outputs[3]
    elif self.det_algorithm == 'DB':
        preds['maps'] = outputs[0]
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: i have tried passing arg for TextDetector , still getting the same error

Comment: what have you passed as arguments?

Comment: i passed image and a dictionary. 

args = Utility.param_args()
text_detector = predict_det.TextDetector(args)
dt_boxes, elapse = text_detector(img)

Comment: when i am trying to run this command (print(callable(text_detector))) the output is FALSE coming...something wrong with my TextDetector file but don't know what. I am trying to run it in a "__call__" method

Comment: found the issue, my "__call__" method was inside "__init__" method hence the error